# Remove duplicate in key-value pattern

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I have an input which consist of duplicates.

```
"Jacob":56002
"Mark":1002
"Jacob":56002
"Jacob":1001
"Mark":1002
```

Desired Output:

```
"Jacob":56002
"Jacob":1001
"Mark":1002
```

Comment: Is that input a series of lines of text? in which case the key:value pattern is irrelevant: you just want to find the unrepeated line.

Comment: how to get it.?

Answer (score 1):

Load the file into python, split lines, and then dedup.

```py
data = """
"Jacob":56002
"Mark":1002
"Jacob":56002
"Jacob":1001
"Mark":1002
"""

spl = data.split('\n')
set([x.strip() for x in spl if x])

Out[46]: {'"Jacob":1001', '"Jacob":56002', '"Mark":1002'}
```